# Removing the namespace from SOAP request

Tags: java, delphi, visual-studio-2010, soap, delphi-2007

I have imported a WSDL and use it to send a SOAP request. It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <Calculate xmlns="urn:xx.WSDL.xxxxxWebService">
            <ContractdocumentIn>
                <AL>
                ...More XML...
```

The problem is the `xmlns="urn:xx.WSDL.xxxxxWebService"` part in the Calculate element. The web service cannot accept this. The web service doesn't like namespaces like this...

Using [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) I found this request to work just fine:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:col="http://example.com.service.xxx/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <col:Calculate>
            <ContractdocumentIn>
                <AL>
                    ...More XML...
```

So, how do I change the request from the first to the second version? (Without using dirty tricks!) 
(Re-importing is not a problem if this would result in the proper request format.)

**Again: no dirty tricks allowed, like hacking the request stream to modify it!**

---

And while I haven't completely tested it, it seems that C#/VS2010 and Delphi 2010 are also unable to use the web service that I'm trying to call. A web service that seems to be written in Java. [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) happens to be written in Java, thus we have a Java client talking to a Java service, which seems to work just fine. But any other client?
Anyways, time to add two more tags: "Java", since it's a Java service, and "vs2010" because .NET also dislikes this service.
And I was about to write a wrapper around this service in .NET, hoping that would work... It doesn't. So this is a very serious flaw, possibly a Java flaw...

Comment: Good luck. I had to resort to dirty tricks.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I can probably solve it by using dirty tricks, but management doesn't agree with that. So the code needs to be clean.

Comment: The SOAP code provides hooks for you to examine the XML that is being sent, and to modify it if you need to. It supports manual manipulation explicitly. And the code would be there - nothing "dirty" about post-build manipulation. May not be as nice as automatic, but no one should be worrying about it.

Comment: I know. Would not be too difficult, even. Capture the BeforeExecute event, read the XML, transform it with a stylesheet, then recreate the stream with the new XML. That's what I suggested to management. They are convinced that this is just too complex and now I need to find some other solution. If there is none, they will have to accept that, though...

Comment: "less complex" is more dirty, but simple.  I use StringReplace to strip out the in-line namespaces, and inject the "ns:" prefixes where needed.  IMO, it would be a lot better if Delphi could just create the same XML that SoapUI does, to make it easy to verify that "we're doing it right".  Otherwise, when the finger pointing starts, there always seem to be more Java and .Net guys, so their way is "right", and the Delphi side has to fix their stuff to make it "look right".

Comment: If no good answers show up, I will chip in for a bounty.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If a Service expects:

```
  <col:Calculate>
     <ContractdocumentIn>
         <AL>
```

and Delphi SOAP is sending...

```
    <Calculate xmlns="urn:xx.WSDL.xxxxxWebService">
        <ContractdocumentIn>
            <AL>
```

... the problem is that ContractdocumentIn is an unqualified element and (until Delphi XE) Delphi SOAP did not support unqualified elements that are top level elements of an operation. Top level elements are parameters of the function and there is nowhere to store the fact that the underlying element must be unqualified; for elements that map to properties, we use the Index of the property to store away the IS_UNQL flag.

BTW, it's not necessary to use a prefix. The Service will (should) also accept:

```
    <Calculate xmlns="urn:xx.WSDL.xxxxxWebService">
        <ContractdocumentIn xmlns="">
            <AL>
```

The latter is more verbose but it's equivalent to the prefix case.

In Delphi XE the importer stores away the fact that a particular parameter maps to an unqualified element and the runtime acts on this information. I've posted patches based on the XE implementation for D2010 and D2007 in the newsgroup when it came up in a thread recently:

https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=43057

If someone needs access to them (they were in the attachments area but might have scrolled off), please email me and I'll make them available. [bbabet at embarcadero dot com]

Cheers,

Bruneau

Comment: Nice explanation!  Thanks.
I'm using D2005 with D2007 patches for the SOAP libraries. Do you think your fixes to the D2007 patches would work for me?

Comment: Yes, it should. The patch I posted is here: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=290788

Comment: If you run into problems, please, point me to (or email me) the WSDL and I'll investigate. Cheers!

Comment: Very good explanation. Actually, the service I'm calling prefers to have an additional namespace for 'col:' like this: `<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:col="http://example.com.service/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><col:Calculate><ContractdocumentIn>` but fortunately, it also accepts `<Calculate xmlns="http://colan.ogconnect.service.wzp/"><ContractdocumentIn xmlns="">`.

Comment: This approach is looking pretty good, we're experimenting now to see the impact on some of our existing services. i.e. "how many ugly StringReplace operations could we get rid of?" We'll report back next week with our conclusions.

Comment: Accepted this as answer because it explains why this problem occurs. The patch is very useful too! Plus, it confirms the solution I've found.

Answer (score 8):

OMG! It took lots of coffee and plenty of sleep depravation but I managed to solve my problem! It's reasonable simple too...
First I import the WSDL, as expected. This will generate several TRemotable classes. Then, for each TRemotable which needs a different namespace, I override the ObjectToSOAP() method! (And include XMLIntf to the WSDL source.) In my case with code like this for several of the remotable types:

```
function AL2.ObjectToSOAP( RootNode, ParentNode: IXMLNode; const ObjConverter: IObjConverter; const NodeName, NodeNamespace, ChildNamespace: InvString; ObjConvOpts: TObjectConvertOptions; out RefID: InvString ): IXMLNode;
begin
  Result := inherited ObjectToSOAP( RootNode, ParentNode, ObjConverter, NodeName, '', '', ObjConvOpts, RefID );
end;
```

Which worked in Delphi XE. In Delphi 2007 I had to use units XMLIntf and XMLDoc plus this code on the input type:

```
function ContractdocumentInType.ObjectToSOAP(RootNode, ParentNode: IXMLNode; const ObjConverter: IObjConverter; const Name, URI: InvString; ObjConvOpts: TObjectConvertOptions; out RefID: InvString): IXMLNode;

  procedure AlterChildren(Child: IXMLNode);
  var
    I: Integer;
  begin
    if (Child.NodeType = ntElement) then Child.SetAttributeNS('xmlns', '', '');
    for I := 0 to Pred(Child.ChildNodes.Count) do
      AlterChildren(Child.ChildNodes[I]);
  end;

begin
  Result := inherited ObjectToSOAP(RootNode, ParentNode, ObjConverter, Name, '', ObjConvOpts, RefID);
  AlterChildren(Result);
end;
```

It is a hack, in my opinion. But it's not a very dirty one. It's a bit of experimenting, capturing the SOAP requests and responses to check their content and to see if it uses the proper namespaces. Unfortunately, Delphi XE does a far better job at this than Delphi 2007.

Still, I keep this Q open for any better solutions...

---

Btw, to add the `col:` to the output, I also had to change this line in the WSDL `RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(Calculate, 'http://colan.ogconnect.service.wzp/', 'Calculate');` to this: `RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(Calculate, 'http://colan.ogconnect.service.wzp/', 'cal:Calculate');`. The result then becomes `<cal:Calculate xmlns:cal="http://example.webservice/">`. Ont more thing needs to be done, though: moving that `xmlns:cal` to the xml header. But as it is now, it works for me.

---

Another note: for the WSDL I used the following settings: 'One Outparam is return', 'Unwind literal params', 'Generate destructors', 'Warning comments', '**emit literal types**', 'Map string to widestring'. Other options are: 'Generate verbose information about types and interfaces', 'Ignore porttypes with HTTP Bindings', 'Validate enumeration members', 'Import fault types', 'Import header types', 'Process included and imported schemas', 'Generate class alias as class types', 'Allow Out parameters' and 'Process nillable and optional elements'. The **emit literal types** was practical because it generates a class around the single method that I was calling. Unfortunately, this won't help much either, although the class would help you to modify the SOAP request on the upper level within the envelope by overriding the ObjectToSOAP() method.
Creation of the envelope itself is in the SOAPEnv unit and it's used in the OPToSOAPDomConv unit. Unfortunately, I haven't found an easy method to access the envelope itself to alter the header to add this additional namespace. Then again, I could override the TSOAPDomConv class with my own version that does add the additional namespace. But the code is working for me now, and as my father told me, when he learned me to program: never fix anything that isn't broken.

Comment: Looks promising - I'm going to give it a whirl.  This may save a lot of time/pain on a big project coming up, so I'm happy to contribute bounty points into the discussion.

Comment: Did it really give you output like this: <col:Calculate>

Comment: I think this may give me a nice place to hook into, but I may need to do more work in the AlterChildren function.

Comment: The col:calculate was done with a second trick. See extended answer.

Comment: I'm going to make a new class: TRemotableFix which does the ObjectToSOAP override. Then I can simply modify the generated proxy to change all/most TRemotable to TRemotableFix, add the Uses for my new intermediate class, and then make the edits to the RegisterXSClass.  I want a "cook-book" solution that could be quickly applied to any proxy class, as I need to be able to re-consume the WSDL later on and not break everything.  i.e. changes to the proxy class need to be short and sweet, and easily discovered with svn history.

Comment: I've considered doing the same, but the people behind the web service have been told to not alter their service, unless they're willing to solve this problem at their side. :-)

Comment: Am still hoping for an even better solution, though... But the more I search in the Delphi 2007 code, the more I think this is just the best solution. The ObjectToSOAP() seems to be made virtual just for this purpose...