# How do I change the SOAP structure in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, soap

I have imported a wsdl into Delphi and it doesn't work with the server. I have been told I need to change the structure to

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"      xmlns:api="http://api.service.api.xxxxxxx.com/"> 
<soapenv:Header/> 
<soapenv:Body> 
<api:openApiConnection> 
<login>XXXXXXXXX</login> 
<pwd>XXXXXXXX</pwd> 
<key>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</key> 
</api:openApiConnection> 
</soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Rather than Delphi's

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<openApiConnection xmlns="http://api.service.api.xxxxx.com/">
<login xmlns="">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</login>
<pwd xmlns="">XXXXXXXXXXXX</pwd>
<key xmlns="">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</key>
</openApiConnection>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Any ideas? Or do I have to roll my own?

Thanks

Comment: what delphi versiona are you using?

Comment: I suppose you have this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154585/removing-the-namespace-from-soap-request

Comment: Voting to 'leave open' as per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139961/whats-the-policy-on-closing-unique-questions-with-overlapping-but-non-duplicat